# Checking if build macro already processed ancestor node

Tags: macros, haxe

Assume you have type-building macro, interface invoking `@:autoBuild` using aforementioned macro, class implementing the interface and class extending it. Macro will fail if the class doesn't contain specific method.

Like so:

**Macro.hx**

```
package;

import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.Type;

class Macro
{
    macro public function build():Array<Field>
    {
        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();

        for (field in fields) {
            if (field.name == "hello") {
                //Do some modifications

                return fields;       
            }
        }

        Context.error('${Context.getLocalClass().toString()} doesn\'t contain a method `hello`', Context.currentPos());

        return null;
    }
}
```

**I.hx**

```
package;

@:autoBuild(Macro.build())
interface I {}
```

**Foobar.hx**

```
package;

class Foobar implements I
{
    public function new() {}

    public function hello(person:String)
    {
        return 'Hello $person!';
    }
}
```

**Foo.hx**

```
package;

@:keep
class Foo extends Foobar {}
```

As you can see, we're checking if field "hello" exists. However, `Context.getBuildFields` contains only fields of current class, and build will fail for `Foo`.

This is where my idea comes in: Why not just check if any ancestor was already processed? We'll change Macro.hx to reflect just that:

**Macro.hx**

```
package;

import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.Type;

class Macro
{
    macro public function build():Array<Field>
    {
        var c = Context.getLocalClass().get();
        if(isAncestorAlreadyProcessed(c)) {
            return null;
        }

        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();

        for (field in fields) {
            if (field.name == "hello") {
                //Do some modifications

                c.meta.add(":processed", [], c.pos);  

                return fields;       
            }
        }      

        Context.error('${Context.getLocalClass().toString()} doesn\'t contain a method `hello`', Context.currentPos());

        return null;
    }

    private static function isAncestorAlreadyProcessed(c:ClassType)
    {
        if (c.meta.has(":processed")) return true;
        if (c.superClass == null) return false;

        return isAncestorAlreadyProcessed(c.superClass.t.get());
    }
}
```

And for the main questions: Do I misunderstand haxe macro type building? Is there a more viable way of making this work? Does my code fail in specific scenarios? Are there any harmful side-effects caused by this code?

I'm trying to resolve [this](https://github.com/fponticelli/edge/issues/17) issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is the way to go, use metadata to store information of the classes you processed ([source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/haxelang/WEZ6_47rgqo/ctPYmUWRFQAJ)).

Another way, if you don't need this information at runtime, is to use a static array on a dedicated class like [here](https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexAnnotation/blob/371aa84e1825bd2bc14b17fb91d70894ff4f76db/src/hex/annotation/AnnotationReader.hx). Afterwards, you can even push this information in your compiled code, see [here](https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexInject/blob/00555f194c9f92d76c490d9505b5d44f6100089e/src/hex/di/annotation/AnnotationReader.hx).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Only in haxe community, one answer, but specifically resolving my problem. Thank you!